# Should I get an sd card or an SSD for storing data? Should I wait?

Tags: ssd, data-storage, sd-card

I have a galaxy s7+ tab with 1TB expandable memory. While I don't have any quite obvious need for storage as of now, I am that kind of guy who somehow finds way to fill my storage. Most of my storage would contain videos mainly and sometimes videos that are accessed by apps like Udemy.

Currently I saw a 1 TB class 10, A1, UHS 1 SD card which costs inr 8815 (on offer).

And a 1TB SSD around inr 8500 (I haven't checked the specs)

In favor of SD card, it is handy to use in my tablet considering that I don't have to plug it and carry around. Also I can use it to store the app data as well, conveniently. And this model has a 10year warranty (I haven't read the T&C).

Regarding the performance I think an external SSD connected via USB C cable would be faster than accessing data from SD card. And that too I can double it up as my storage for my PC as well (not primarily important). In addition since now most of the upcoming phones and tablets are dropping the support for expandable memory, I am not hoping to see a drop in price of SD card in future. Although I can expect a drop in the price of SSDs in future.

Also I have seen a lot of SD cards getting corrupt within a few years. But I have also seen some of them to last like 7 years. So does SSDs have more life than SD cards on average?

Finally should I go for an SD card or get a SSD? And If I should get an SD card its not worth the wait right?

Comment: That SD card seems pretty cheap for 1TB. One of the cheapest 1TB SD cards where I live cost like €155 (about 12000 indian rupees). That SSD price looks way better and the chances are lower that is a scam

Comment: waiting is generally not reccomended though, except in a shortage

Comment: I believe SSDs have a higher life expectancy than SD cards, generally because the chips are not compromising anything for smaller physical size. A lot of "corrupt" SD cards can be repaired too though, it's just that most devices that use SD cards don't have the tools to do it so the user assumes the card is completely broken.

Comment: @Romen I didn't know there was a way to repair SD card. Yeah it is true most people discard it once the memory gets corrupt. But 10 year warranty is kind of like a loss to the company since within 10 year most memory storage devices will get corrupt or fail.

Comment: Having a 10 year warranty requires the user to a) remember & b) still have the receipt. It's one of those things that will almost never be claimed against, nor would it get your data back. Whilst it is true that SD cards *can* be recovered in many circumstances, it requires tools simply not in the consumer market, expensive & highly specialist. You should consider a dead SD card just that - dead. They have a remarkable propensity for simply dying suddenly for 'no reason'. Don't trust one with the only copy of any data, ever.

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't to intend to store data that are relevant for long term. Often I will be flushing it down every 2 or 3 months. But these sandisk storages can be registered on their website and you will have access to the serial key as well. Also since most electronic purchases have now been made online, the soft copy of the invoice will be available with the e-commerce site or we can simply store it in the cloud. Although I think the most relevant point would be will it become useless by that time. Having 2 Gb pendrive was a luxury some 10 years back.